# MT4 to trading view alerts? Create trading view alert API

Tags: tradingview-api, metatrader4, mt4

Hi I am looking for a method to be able to get my MT4 alerts onto the trading view system so that I can be able to close my Mt4 terminal.

Are there any ready solutions?

If not I am looking to code my solution but I need a way to create the trading view alert.

Does trading view have an API function or is there an library that I can use.

Many thanks.